# How Assigning TupleN value to *: type variable works in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3, hlist, dotty, singleton-type

From the type hierarchy tree in scala

- let a:`Tuple2[Int,Int]`, I know `Tuple2[Int,Int]` extends from `Product2[Int,Int]`;
- let b:`1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple` has type `Tuple` (refined as `Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple`)

They are different types and don't have any parent relation. The only thing they both have is `Product`, they both extend from `Product`.

But I can assign `a` to `b` and opposite,  why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala 3, the `Tuple1`...`Tuple22` types are synthetically modified by the compiler to extend the `*:` types. That is, `Tuple2[A, B]` is modified to extend `A *: B *: EmptyTuple` (which extends `Tuple`).

Therefore, you can assign a `Tuple2[Int, Int]` to a `Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple`. Likewise, the reverse is possible because a `A *: ... EmptyTuple` will be treated like a `TupleN` whenever it can (<= 22 type arguments).

Comment: There is no reasons except compiler magic

Answer (score 1):

They are different types but that does not mean that they are unrelated. `1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple` is a subtype of `Tuple2[Int,Int]` because the singleton literals `1` and `2` are subtypes of `Int` and the type params of `Tuple2` are covariant.

You can widen an instance of `1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple` to `Tuple2[Int,Int]` but not the other way around.

Please note that `Tuple2[A, B]` and `A *: B *: EmptyTuple` are equivalent. `1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple` is assumed to a type-level expression based on question's syntax, but if it were a value-level expression then the type of it would be `Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple` which would be equivalent to `Tuple2[Int,Int]`. In that case instance of both types would be "assignable" to one another.

Code for reference:

```scala
@main def main() =
  type T1 = Tuple2[Int, Int]
  type T2 = 1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple

  val t1a: T1 = (1, 2) //compiles
  val t2a: T2 = (1, 2) //compiles
  val t1b: T1 = (2, 1) //compiles
//  val t2b: T2 = (2, 1) // does not compile

//  t1a: T2 //does not compile
  t2a: T1 //compiles

  summon[1 <:< Int] // compiles
//  summon[1 =:= Int] // does not compile
  summon[T2 <:< T1] //compiles
//  summon[T1 <:< T2] // does not compile
//  summon[T1 =:= T2] // does not compile

  //these are the same types, not exclusively subtypes of one another
  summon[Tuple2[Int, Int] =:= Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple]
  summon[Tuple2[Int, Int] <:< Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple]
  summon[Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple <:< Tuple2[Int, Int]]
```

Comment: I don't think @LinLee is referring to the singleton type `1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple`, I think he just means the `Int *: Int *: EmptyTuple`.

Comment: @MichaelZajac yes, based on the result that is most likely what happened,  but if you were to compare `a:Tuple2[Int,Int]` with `b:1 *: 2 *: EmptyTuple` that would be a comparison between types, and in both cases the values would be the same